# Remove all files contain specific string - Bash

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I have these bad data

```
AWS-Console.pngcrop-AWS-Console.png                                                                                    
Alimofire.pngcrop-Alimofire.png                                                                                        
Amazon-ECR-.pngcrop-Amazon-ECR-.png                                                                                    
Amazon-ECS.pngcrop-Amazon-ECS.png                                                                                      
Amazon-RDS.pngcrop-Amazon-RDS.png                                                                                      
Angular.pngcrop-Angular.png                                                                                            
AngularJS.pngcrop-AngularJS.png 
.... 1000 more
```

I'm trying to delete them

I've tried

```
ls public/assets/fe/img/skill/ | grep crop | rm -rf *crop*
ls public/assets/fe/img/skill/ | grep crop | rm -rf
rm -rf $(ls public/assets/fe/img/skill/ | grep crop)
```

None of them work ...

Comment: There are a few; a simple Google should've worked. `rm *crop*` or `find -type f -name '*crop*' -delete`

Comment: `for f in *.png; do if [[ $f == *crop* ]]; then echo rm -- "$f"; fi; done`

Comment: Isn't the path missing from the `rm` command?

Comment: `find . -type f -name '*crop*.png' ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rm` can handle the glob expressions that `ls` handles:

```
rm public/assets/fe/img/skill/*crop*
```

Comment: What ... this is so cool, I can't beleive I forgot ab that, I'm close.

Comment: This is a great answer, until it hit's `arg_max`.

Comment: What is `arg_max` ?

Comment: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/  Only for large amount of files, in your case it seems it did not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `find` command instead

```
find . -name "*crop*" -type f -exec rm -i {} \;
```

- `-type f` will specify to search file only and avoid directories
- `-exec` requires the command input to end with  `\;`, the `{}` being substitute by the result of the command
- the `-i` will ask you to confirm ; remove it once sure what you do.
- *advice* display the result beforehand with `-print` in place of `-exec ...`

  ```
    find . -name "*crop*" -type f -print
  ```

More [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12902/how-to-run-find-exec.) where your question would find more accurate answers

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your commands is the missing path in the output of the `ls` command.

`ls public/assets/fe/img/skill/ | grep crop` will retur e.g. `AWS-Console.pngcrop-AWS-Console.png` which is passed to `rm`. But `rm AWS-Console.pngcrop-AWS-Console.png` fails because there is no such file in the current directory. It should be `rm public/assets/fe/img/skill/AWS-Console.pngcrop-AWS-Console.png` instead.

Adding `-d` to the `ls` command should do the trick:

```sh
ls -d public/assets/fe/img/skill/ | grep crop | rm -rf
rm -rf $(ls -d public/assets/fe/img/skill/ | grep crop)
```

As pointed out in other answers, other solutions exist, including:

```sh
rm public/assets/fe/img/skill/*crop*
find public/assets/fe/img/skill/ -name "*crop*" -type f -exec rm -i {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a really large number of files (apparently wasn't in your case), `xargs` can [speed up the process](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/linux-xargs-vs-exec/). This applies for a lot of things you might want to read from a pipe.

```
 find . -name "*crop*" -type f | xargs rm
```

The main advantage of using `find` here is that it's an easy way to ignore directories. If that's not an issue, let the OS handle all that.

```
printf "%s\n" public/assets/fe/img/skill/*crop* | xargs rm
```

If you need to be able to pick up files *in* subdirectories -

```
shopt -s globstar # double asterisks not include arbitrary preceding paths
printf "%s\n" public/assets/fe/img/skill/**crop* | xargs rm
```

You might want to look over the list first, though.

```
printf "%s\n" public/assets/fe/img/skill/*crop* >crop.lst 
# check the list - vi, grep, whatever satisfies you.
xargs rm < crop.lst  # fast-delete them in bulk
```